# zip only directory content (files and subdir)

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-pipeline

For instance I've the following workspacestructure:

```
├───automation_scripts
├───dist
│   └───assets
│   │    └───images
│   │
    |___index.html
├───node_modules
|___src
|___web.config
```

I want to only zip the content of **dist** and **web.config**

right now I'm doing this:

```
zip zipFile: "${OCTOPUS_PACKAGE_NAME}", archive: false, glob: "dist/**, Web.config"
```

this results in:

```
├───output.zip
    ├───dist
    │   └───assets
    │   │   └───images
    │   │
        |___index.html
    |___web.config
```

but I want:

```
├───output.zip
        ├───assets
        │   │   └───images
        │   │
            |___index.html
        |___web.config
```

How do I modify my filters: `glob: "dist/**, web.config"` to use the right Ant Pattern to achieve my result?

Comment: not sure but it seems it wotrths to try `zip zipFile: "${OCTOPUS_PACKAGE_NAME}", dir: "dist", archive: false, glob: "**/*, ../web.config"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CD into the dir to just grab the contents 
(ZIP works the same on the CLI, we needed to be in the dir to not get the folder structure)

```
dir('dist') {
    zip zipFile: "${OCTOPUS_PACKAGE_NAME}", archive: false, glob: "**/*, ../Web.config"
}
```

Comment: `dist` as parameter to the `dir` step should be quoted.